# registration-url parameter fails for fb:login-button if oauth 2.0 is enabled

Tags: facebook, authentication, oauth, firebug

I'm trying to get the registration flow for Facebook login working.  Here's a bare-bones example:

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
    <head>
      <title>My Facebook Login Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>

      <div id="fb-root"></div>

      <script type="text/javascript">
         FB.init({ 
            appId:'xxxxxxxxxxx', 
            cookie:true, 
            status:true, 
            xfbml:true,
            channelUrl  : 'http://<myWebSite>/channel.html',
            oauth:true
         });
      </script>

     <fb:login-button registration-url="http://<myWebSite>/register"/>
    </body>
 </html>
```

(The only things I've replaced above are the website and the appID)

If I try it like this, the login button shows up, but clicking it causes FireBug to report 'Unknown status: undefined' in the browser log.  If I remove the 'oauth=true' line though, it works.  I'm trying to adhere to the new oauth 2.0 standard, so I'd like to leave it in.  Has anyone else run into this?  Seems like if this was a bug, it would have been caught pretty early on.

Comment: I'm also seeing this problem. As soon as I remove the oauth: true It works.

Comment: A bug is filed here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/223444304375753

Comment: May be dumb - have you enabled the migration in the app settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the 'registration-url' parameter is no longer supported by , take a look in the documentation of it. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/login/

Just check if the user is logged in via the JS-SDK